# How to return a 2D array method

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I keep getting an error because my code won't return a 2D array.
How do I store the values I want into answer.

```
static int[][] findPairsWithGivenDifference(int[] arr, int k) {

   int sizeOfArray = arr.length;
   int[][] answer;
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   int first = 0, last = 1;

   while(last < sizeOfArray && first < sizeOfArray){
     if(first != last && arr[last] - arr[first] == k){

         // this is where the problem is, how do I return these values in
         // [[0, 1], [2, 5]] format
         answer = {arr[first]arr[last]};
         first++;
         last++;
   }else if(arr[last] - arr[first] < k){
       last++;
   }else{
       first++;
  }
} // end of while

return answer;
}
```

Comment: _"I keep getting an error because my code won't return a 2D array"_ - What is the error, and what do you mean by "won't return a 2D array"?

Comment: @JimGarrison the error is on line 10. Where it has answer = {arr[first],arr[second]}, this won't work. How do I store first and second in a 2d array? Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to reinitialize the array each iteration, and you're not initializing it correctly, you would need to do something along the lines of `{{x},{y}}`, but that's not including the fact that on initialization java requires you to specify the ranges of each dimension of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you tried to put values in a 2D array, `int[][] answer`, in this way:

```
 answer = {arr[first]arr[last]};
```

But the correct way to put values in 2d array are:

```
answer[rowNumber][coulmnNumber]=someValue;
example: answer[0][1]=5;
```

Side note:

1. In your method `findPairsWithGivenDifference` you are returning a `int[][]`. In you current code you return  `int[][]` might not initialize, because you are initializeing the 2D array(`answer`) in a `if` statement. 
   You need to initialize the return value outside the `if` statment. One way to do it is to change this line of code:

   int[][] answer;

   to:

   int[][] answer= new int [wantedRowsNumbers][wantedCoulmnsNumbers];